# Maintain session state data in a way that keeps it tied to the authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, session-state

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 Application that is essentially a proxy to a database. To login, users must provide their database user and name. (I know it isn't a good idea to use database users as application users, but I didn't design the database, so don't blame me.)

When my users log in, I would like to store in a session variable their username and password:

```
Session["UserID"] = TheConnectionStringBuilder.UserID;
Session["Password"] = TheConnectionStringBuilder.Password;
```

However, session state is not intrinsically tied to the authentication cookie, and this could cause problems later. Is there any way to keep session state data in such a way that it remains tied to the authentication cookie?

Comment: Why not store that data in the users' auth cookie.  Its pretty bad to store plain passwords like that anywhere, but the users' cookie is at least encrypted.  This way you can avoid session hijacking issues...

Comment: What problems do you think you might encounter?

Comment: @James Connell: How do I do that?

Comment: @james - the user's auth cookie would be the last place I'd be storing their credentials.

Comment: @james - remember this? http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2010/10/11/aspnet-padding-oracle-vulnerability/

Comment: @Kev: So... where could I store them?

Comment: Could you expand on why you can't use the session to store the credentials?

Comment: I agree that session state is not intrinsically tied to the authentication cookie BUT you can achieve that by setting the timeout for both the cookies to same. On your Session End, you can call singout and on logout you can abandon the session.

Comment: @sajoshi: What if the user deletes the session cookie, but not the authentication cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way could be matching session state time-out with authentication time-out using configuration. For example,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms timeout="30" />
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="31" />
```

Yet another way would be to store credentials into some persistent store (such as file) tagged with some generated key and then keep this key in authentication cookie. However, I feel this is a round about way of doing things and I would rather go with session approach.

For some reason, if you don't find the user id/password in the session (for example, application pool recycle), you can force user to re-login (by using [FormsAuthentication.SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) followed by [RedirectToLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirecttologinpage.aspx)).

Comment: This mechanism still has a weakness: What happens if the user deletes the Session State cookie, but not the authentication cookie?

Comment: @Eduardo, not really, if user deletes the session cookie then session would expire and that would trigger the condition is last para i.e. if you don't find user id/pwd, you force user log-out. You can put such check on-demand (i.e. when database is accessed) or in base page/global.asax.